# Calculating the inverse of a matrix with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a large pandas.DataFrame - which is a square matrix with header and index, and I am trying to use pandas' capabilities to calculate the inverse of that matrix, without going directly through numpy.

I want to stay within a pandas framework to keep the headings of my data frame. I could use the [`pandas.as_matrix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) function, but that turns it into an ndarray and I loose all the information provided by the headings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3), list('abc'), list('xyz'))
df
```

[image]

calculate the inverse (with numpy, let's not be crazy)

```
df_inv = pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.pinv(df.values), df.columns, df.index)
df_inv
```

[image]

notice I use `pinv` for the pseudo inverse

then check

```
df_inv.dot(df)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the "with numpy, let's not get crazy" part. Many people don't seem to understand that pandas is just a thin abstraction layer on top of numpy.

Comment: I get the first step of using np.linalg.pinv. But the result of this is the inverse, right? Then why do we need the next step df_inv.dot(df)? What are we checking here?

Comment: @TDS we are checking that the matrix multiplication results in the identity matrix.  And it does.