# Python - Inversing complex arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, matrix-inverse

I have some square matrix with complex values and want to inverse it.

If I try:

```
(my_matrix)**(-1)
```

I get:

```
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 to a negative or complex power
```

If I try:

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.inv(my_matrix)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv
```

How to invert complex Array?

Comment: Can you please show a [mre]?

Comment: You can't use simply python to work with matrixes. You may use pandas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858835/calculating-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-with-pandas

Comment: Tell us more about that array.  `shape`, `dtype`, and some values (or all if not too large)

Comment: `x**-1` is element wise division, unless `x` is `np.matrix`.

Comment: Apparently `my_matrix` is not a numpy `array` or `matrix`, or if it is, its data type is not a numeric type.   What is `type(my_matrix)`?  If it is a numpy array or matrix, what is `my_matrix.dtype`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, object dtype produces those errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use strictly python to work on matrixes and analyze arrays. I would recommend using Pandas or Numpy, which are easy-to-use libraries that will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Thought Numpy works, I've used it and it works for me. I think you need to use other libraries if you do it with numpy

Comment: So you inversed array with COMPLEX values?

Comment: Semi-Complex, it will work. I use Jupyter Notebook IDE

Comment: I use jupyter too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232746/discussion-between-boetis-and-wiktor-kujawa).

Answer (score 0):

From the sample posted in the discussion (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232746/discussion-between-boetis-and-wiktor-kujawa) I was able to recreate a (4,4) complex_dtype array (it took some tedious editing):

```
In [501]: np.array(my_matrix)
Out[501]: 
array([[-4.90995593-0.0388j    , -0.        -0.j        ,
        -1.21084206-0.9213362j , -0.05935173-0.04516105j],
       [-0.        -0.j        , -4.90995593-0.0388j    ,
        -0.05935173-0.04516105j, -1.21084206-0.9213362j ],
       [-1.21084206+0.9213362j , -0.05935173+0.04516105j,
        -4.90995593-0.0388j    , -0.        -0.j        ],
       [-0.05935173+0.04516105j, -1.21084206+0.9213362j ,
        -0.        -0.j        , -4.90995593-0.0388j    ]])
In [502]: x=_
In [503]: np.linalg.inv(x)
Out[503]: 
array([[-0.22536285+2.16108358e-03j, -0.00234657+6.35524029e-05j,
         0.05633771+4.13312304e-02j,  0.003354  +2.44488004e-03j],
       [-0.00234657+6.35524029e-05j, -0.22536285+2.16108358e-03j,
         0.003354  +2.44488004e-03j,  0.05633771+4.13312304e-02j],
       [ 0.0548569 -4.32773491e-02j,  0.00325069-2.58066414e-03j,
        -0.22536285+2.16108358e-03j, -0.00234657+6.35524029e-05j],
       [ 0.00325069-2.58066414e-03j,  0.0548569 -4.32773491e-02j,
        -0.00234657+6.35524029e-05j, -0.22536285+2.16108358e-03j]])
```

The `scipy.linalg.inv` does the same thing.

```
In [505]: x.dtype
Out[505]: dtype('complex128')
In [506]: x.shape
Out[506]: (4, 4)
```

### with object dtype:

Producing your errors:

```
In [512]: np.linalg.inv(x.astype(object))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-512-615f0ffc3570>", line 1, in <module>
    np.linalg.inv(x.astype(object))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in inv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 545, in inv
    ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv

In [513]: x.astype(object)**-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-513-65fe9688f840>", line 1, in <module>
    x.astype(object)**-1
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 to a negative or complex power
```